# How to access the model from the controller in zend?

Tags: zend-framework, model, controller

This is the controller

```
class LocationController 
{
     .....
      public function testareAction(){ 
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
        $myarray =  $_POST['data_post'];
        $product_ids = $_POST['product_ids'];
        echo "test1";
        $model = new Application_Model_OrderNames(); 
        echo "test2";
        $model -> saveOrderNames();

    }
}
```

and this is the model :

```
<?php
    class OrderNames {
        public function __construct(){

        }
        public function saveOrderNames(){
            return 1;
        } 
    }   
?>
```

What im doing wrong ? Why i cannot access the "test2" string in the browser?  thx

this is my full controller class :

```
<?php

use Application\Model\Cronos,
    Application\Model\DbTable;

class LocationController extends \Lunchbox\Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        if (!($locationUrl = $this->_getParam('locationUrl'))) {
            throw new \Zend_Controller_Action_Exception('Location URL was not provided.', 404);
        }        

        $this->maiDivClass = "block clear step1";

        // get Location row
        $mapper = new DbTable\Location();
        $sql = $mapper->select()->where('url = ?', $locationUrl);

        if (!($this->view->location = $mapper->fetchRowActive($sql))) {
            throw new \Zend_Controller_Action_Exception('Location not found', 404);
        }

        // set active markup for location menu
        $this->_helper->layout()->locationMainMenuUrl = $this->view->location->url;

        // SEO
        $this->setSeo(
            $this->view->location->meta_title, 
            $this->view->location->meta_description, 
            $this->view->location->meta_keywords
        );

        // get day from param
        $dayName = $this->_getParam('day', Cronos::getCurrentDayName());

        $this->view->dayNo = Cronos::getWeekDayNumber($dayName);
        if ($this->view->dayNo === false) {
            throw new \Zend_Controller_Action_Exception('Invalid weekday provided.', 404);
        }

        $this->view->selectedDate = Cronos::getDateWithOffset($this->view->dayNo); // get date offset
        $this->view->categMapper  = new DbTable\Categories();

        $appCfg = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini', APPLICATION_ENV);
        $this->view->s3 = "http://".$appCfg->custom->s3->bucket;
        $imgMapper = new Application_Model_Mapper_Images();
        $this->view->imgs = $imgMapper->fetchAllByLocationId($this->view->location->id);


        /**
         * Show products only for allowed admin emails. Testing only.
         * Admin must be logged in to see products, while the test is on.
         * 
         * To disable, change custom.test.isEnabled flag in app.ini.
         */
        $testCfg = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Config')->custom->test->toArray();
        $isEnabled = (bool) $testCfg['isEnabled'];

        // test is enabled?
        if ($isEnabled) {
            $email = false; 
            $auth  = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
            // grab email, if logged in
            if ($auth->hasIdentity()) { $email = $auth->getIdentity()->email; }

            // has email? check it against config, else don't show products
            $showProducts = ($email) ? in_array($email, (array) $testCfg['email']) : false;

        // test is disabled: always show products
        } else {
            $showProducts = true;
        }

        if ($showProducts) {

            // get categories & products for this date and location
            $prodService = new \Application\Service\Products();
            $this->view->categsWithProds = $prodService->getProducts($this->view->location->id, $this->view->selectedDate); 

            //check days of the week with products
            $week = array();
            $currentDay = Cronos::getWeekDayNumberByDate();
            if($this->view->location->erp_name != "city lbox") {
                for($day=$currentDay;$day<7;$day++)
                {
                    $selectedDate = Cronos::getDateWithOffset($day);
                    $categswithprod = $prodService->getProducts($this->view->location->id, $selectedDate);
                    if(count($categswithprod))
                        $week[] = $day;

                }
                //we need to go to sunday and next week
                for($day=0;$day<$currentDay;$day++)
                {
                    $selectedDate = Cronos::getDateWithOffset($day);
                    $categswithprod = $prodService->getProducts($this->view->location->id, $selectedDate);
                    if(count($categswithprod))
                        $week[] = $day;
                } 
            } else {
                for($day = $currentDay; $day<7;$day++) {
                    $week[] = $day;
                }
                for($day = 0; $day<$currentDay; $day++) {
                    $week[] = $day;
                }
            }

            $this->view->week = $week;
            $specialMenuRows = $this->view->location->getSpecialMenus(new Zend_Date());
            $this->view->specialMenus = $this->view->partial('_partials/specialMenu.phtml', array('specialMenus' => $specialMenuRows));

            $this->view->categsWithProdsALaCarte =  $prodService->getProducts($this->view->location->id, $this->view->selectedDate, 1);

        // no xml; show "Download PDF"
        } else {
            $this->setPdfLink();
            $this->renderScript('location/no_xml.phtml');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set pdfLink view var depending on current location .
     */
    protected function setPdfLink()
    {
        $this->view->pdfLink = false;
        if (strpos($this->view->location->url, 'city')) {
            $this->view->pdfLink = "http://meniu.lunchbox.ro/lunchbox.city.pdf";
        } elseif (strpos($this->view->location->url, 'polus')) {
            $this->view->pdfLink = "http://meniu.lunchbox.ro/lunchbox.polus.pdf";
        } elseif (strpos($this->view->location->url, 'sediu')) {
            $this->view->pdfLink = "http://meniu.lunchbox.ro/lunchbox.sediu.pdf";
        } elseif (strpos($this->view->location->url, 'iulius')) {
            $this->view->pdfLink = "http://meniu.lunchbox.ro/lunchbox.iulius.pdf";
        }        
    }
    public function testareAction(){ 
       // $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
        $myarray =  $_POST['data_post'];
        $product_ids = $_POST['product_ids'];
        $type = 1; 
        echo "tralalalal";
       // $model = new Application_Model_Mapper_Images();
        $model = new Application_Model_OrderNames();
        echo  $model -> saveOrderNames();

        echo "string";
        //$this->view->String = $model -> saveOrderNames();

    }
}
```

and this is the images model class :

```
<?php

class Application_Model_Mapper_Images extends Application_Model_Base_MapperAbstract
{
    protected $dbName = 'location_images';

    /**
     * @param int $locationId
     * @param array $imageNamesArr
     *      Array of basename files.
     * @return false|array
     *      Return boolean false on insert error.
     *      key: new image index, value: basename. I.e. array(1 => 'madonna.jpg')
     */
    public function batchInsertNewProductImages($locationId, array $imageNamesArr)
    {
        $newImgs = array();
        $this->getZDb()->getAdapter()->beginTransaction();

        try {
            foreach ($imageNamesArr as $baseImageName) {
                $newId = $this->getZDb()->insert(array('base_filename' => $baseImageName, 'location_id' => $locationId));
                $newImgs[$newId] = $baseImageName;
            }
            $this->getZDb()->getAdapter()->commit();
            return $newImgs;
        } catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
            $this->getZDb()->getAdapter()->rollBack();
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param int $productId
     * @return array
     *      Container of Application_Model_Object_Image objects.
     */
    public function fetchAllByLocationId($locationId)
    {
        $locationId = (int) $locationId;
        $sql = $this->db->select()
                        ->from('location_images')
                        ->where('location_id = ?', $locationId)
                        ->order('disp_order')
                        ->order('base_filename'); // order alphabetically

        $out = array();
        foreach ($this->db->fetchAll($sql) as $imgRow) {

            $out[] = $imgRow;
        }
        return $out;
    }


    public function reOrderPhotos(array $photos)
    {
        $disp_order = 0;
        foreach ($photos as $photo_id) {
                $sql = $this->db->select()->from('location_images')->where('id = ?', $photo_id);
                //Verify if category exists in table
                if ($this->db->fetchRow($sql) != null) {
                ++$disp_order;
                    if ($photos != "") {
                    //Change menu order
                    $this->db->update('location_images',array('disp_order' => $disp_order), array('id = ?' => $photo_id));
                    }
                }
        }

    }

    public function test()
    {
        $sql = $this->db->insert("location_images", array('base_filename' => 'test.jpg', 'location_id'=>'1','disp_order'=>'22'));

    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @return array
     */
    public function find($id) 
    {
        return $this->getZDb()->find($id)->current();

    }

    /**
     * @param string $imgBaseName
     * @return int
     */
    public function insertNew($imgBaseName)
    {
        $imgBaseName = trim($imgBaseName);

        // omit empty file names
        if (empty($imgBaseName)) { return 0; }

        try {
            return (int) $this->getZDb()->insert(array('base_filename' => (string) $imgBaseName));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    public function saveOrderNames(){

            return 1;

   }
}
```

as you can see the saveOrderNames function is in both OrderNames model and Images model. Can anyone explain me why if i use the "Images" model , my string "string" from the testareAction function from controller it is displayed and if I use OrderNames model, it is not ????

Comment: `Application_Model_OrderNames` is not necessarily the same as `OrderNames`... Just an observation... ;)

Comment: No, that was it. Name your classes properly. Zend Framework is still PHP code; classes you instantiate must exist.

Comment: any ideea why my code does not work ?

Comment: [sigh] because you're trying to instantiate a class that does not exist. A fatal error is thrown and `"test2"` never has a chance to be printed out.

Comment: can you post an example , how can i handle this ?

Comment: RTFM http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html

Comment: I updated my post , please help me with this !

Comment: I have answered your question FOUR TIMES already. This is the fifth and final time: rename your model class.

Comment: I renamed it and still nothing :(

Comment: Do you have an idea about how Zend's autoloader works? Your class names must match their file names and file paths. When you get that right, the autoloader will pick the class up and correctly instantiate it. Other than that, turn on PHP error reporting or get to the server's error log and check the reported errors for insight about what happened. Not only in this particular case; do it always before asking for help with any errors or misbehaviour.

Comment: yeah , I figured it out , finally . thx